# How to reduce the query processing time which is based on the view?

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

-We have a master view that is built on top of many views
-Almost all the relevant mart data is in this view and most of the jobs extract data from this view.

-Simple select to this view translates in 43 maps and 37 reducers
and takes around 1 hour which puts lot of load on the cluster

Following things I tried :

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.groupby.enabled=true;
set hive.exec.orc.split.strategy=BI;
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=true;
SET hive.cbo.enable=true;
SET hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate = true;
```

Here is the query :

```
CREATE VIEW `mstr_pub.vw_customer_info` AS 
SELECT
   field 1, field2, field 3 .....
   SUM(`PTS`.`current_balance`) OVER (PARTITION BY `voucher_cust`.`rel_child`) AS `HPTS`,   
   FLOOR(SUM(`PTS`.`c_balance`) OVER (PARTITION BY `voucher_cust`.`relationships_child`) / 10000)*1000 AS `HPTS_VAL`,
   CAST(IF(UPPER(TRIM(`table1`.`pcplus`)) = 'ACKN', TRUE, FALSE) AS BOOLEAN) AS `NO_PC_PLUS`,

   GET_JSON_OBJECT(`VIRTUAL`.`json`, '$.FIRST_EARN_DATE') AS `FIRST_EARN_DATE`,
   ...  many such GET_JSON_OBJECT calculation fields...

FROM
 `mstr_work`.`vw_voucher_cust_LATEST` `table1` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table2` `table2` 
      ON `table1`.`voucher_id` = `table2`.`voucher_id` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table3` `table3` 
      ON `table2`.`cust_id` = `table3`.`cust_id` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            `table4`.`voucher_id`,
            SUM(`table4`.`current_balance`) AS `CURRENT_BALANCE` 
         FROM
            `mstr_work`.`table4` 
         WHERE
            `table4`.`account_status` = 'ACTIVE' 
         GROUP BY
            `table4`.`voucher_id` 
      )
      `PTS` 
      ON `table1`.`voucher_ID` = `PTS`.`voucher_id` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            `t`.`voucher_id`,
            `t`.`capture_source` 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  `table5`.`voucher_id`,
                  `table5`.`status_capture_source`,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `table5`.`cust_id` 
               ORDER BY
                  `table5`.`status_capture_datetime` DESC) AS `RANK_` 
               FROM
                  `MSTR_CORE`.`table5` 
               WHERE
                  `table5`.`marketing_status` = 'COMMUNICATE' 
                  AND `table5`.`capture_datetime` IS NOT NULL 
            )
            `T` 
         WHERE
            `t`.`rank_` = 1 
      )
      `table6` 
      ON `table1`.`voucher_ID` = `table6`.`voucher_id` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table7` `table7` 
      ON `table2`.`cust_id` = `table7`.`cust_id` 
      AND `table7`.`notification_type` = 'SURVEYS' 
      AND `table2`.`business_effective_ts` = `table7`.`business_effective_ts` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table7` `table7` 
      ON `table2`.`cust_ID` = `table7`.`cust_id` 
      AND `table7`.`notification_type` = 'OFFERALERTS' 
      AND `table7`.`communication_type` = 'EMAIL' 
      AND `table2`.`BUSINESS_EFFECTIVE_TS` = `table7`.`business_effective_ts` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table8` `table8` 
      ON `table1`.`voucher_ID` = `table8`.`voucher_id` 
      AND `table8`.`rbc_customer` IS NOT NULL 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table10` `table10` 
      ON `table2`.`cust_ID` = `table10`.`cust_id` 
      AND `table10`.`home_banner_id` = 'RETAIL' 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT
            `table9`.`zrks`,
            `table9`.`zorg`,
            `table9`.`zext`,
            `table9`.`zweg`,
            `table9`.`zrext` 
         FROM
            `mstr_work`.`table9`
      )
      `table11` 
      ON `table10`.`store_id` = `table11`.`zrks` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table10` `table10` 
      ON `table2`.`cust_ID` = `table10`.`cust_id` 
      AND `table10`.`home_id` = 'SHOPPERS' 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table11` `table12` 
      ON `table10`.`home_store_id` = `table12`.`org` 
      AND `table12`.`parent_type` = 'MKR' 
      AND `table12`.`relationship` = 'CONTAINS' 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`relationships_child` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "SEG_ENTERPRISE" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`RELATIONSHIPS_CHILD` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "NATIONAL_PURCHASE" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`RELATIONSHIPS_CHILD` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "VALUE_SEG_SDM" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            `table14`.`voucher_id`,
            concat('{', concat_ws(',', collect_set(concat('"', `table14`.`attribute_name`, '":"', `table14`.`attribute_value`, '"'))), '}') `JSON` 
         FROM
            `MSTR_CORE`.`table14` 
         GROUP BY
            `table14`.`voucher_id` 
      )
      `VIRTUAL` 
      ON `table1`.`voucher_ID` = `VIRTUAL`.`voucher_id` 
WHERE
   `table2`.`email_address` LIKE '%@%' 
   OR `table1`.`voucher_status` = "DELETED"
```

Request :

Is there anything we can do about this query. 
Only thing i can think of is - to simplify the json set up in the last table before "where clause" and avoid json parsing in "select" parsing to help reduce couple of reducers. I see same table1 i.e table1 is used many times in join. how can i reduce and merge the joins or simplify.  is there such option

any pointers will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple joins with the same table using like this:

```
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`relationships_child` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "SEG_ENTERPRISE" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`RELATIONSHIPS_CHILD` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "NATIONAL_PURCHASE" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
      ON `table1`.`RELATIONSHIPS_CHILD` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
      AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = "VALUE_SEG_SDM"
```

You can easily get rid of multiple joins with the same table using single join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
          `mstr_work`.`table13` as `table13` 
          ON `table1`.`RELATIONSHIPS_CHILD` = `table13`.`household_voucher_id` 
          AND UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) in ("SEG_ENTERPRISE","NATIONAL_PURCHASE","VALUE_SEG_SDM")
```

And when selecting columns from `table13` use `max()`, `sum()`, etc aggregation with case statement:

```
max(case when UPPER(`table13`.`seg_attr`) = SEG_ENTERPRISE then <some column> end) end as SEG_ENTERPRISE_data
```

And the same for `table7`, `table10`

Comment: thanks sir. can i also try to remove the json parsing externally and can i use REGEX in where clause instead of like - with respect to performance.

Comment: @Kumar I do not think it will give you much. Try to use JSON_TUPLE instead of get_json_object + lateral view OUTER if possible(for selecting multiple attributes from the same json) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple

Comment: @Kumar Yep, use regex filter only if you can completely get rid of json parsing, if you are using json attributes it only for filtering.